# How to import a lot of images in julia lang

Tags: julia, flux.jl

[I tried doing it that way but that only gives me the path of those folders but not the images in side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxcYJ.png)

```
### A Pluto.jl notebook ###
# v0.14.3

using Markdown
using InteractiveUtils
using Pkg


Pkg.activate("Project.toml")
Pkg.add("Flux")


#load data
trainData = "../src/dataset/chest_xray/train/"
testData  = "../src/dataset/chest_xray/test/"
validationData  = "../src/dataset/chest_xray/val/"

trainNormal =  "../src/dataset/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/"
TrainPneumonia =  "../src/dataset/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/"

length(trainNormal)
```

@logankilpatrick what I am simply asking is how to import images kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia in julia using the flux package. and the sample code that I posted its me just trying to do so but not working

Comment: Please change this to include a minimum size code example that is in text format, not a screen shot graphic. If you indent your text format code example with 4 spaces on the left hand side of each code line the website will format this as written.

Comment: @Bill or is there any way of accessing the data from kaggle without downloading it in julia?

Comment: @erroDecoder you can use `HTTP.jl` - perhpas this would make a good SO question.

Comment: Okay, I think I see your problem.  You are defining subdirectories for the package, but it may not know what the subdirectories are to be used to do.  Instead, the package needs to have the files in those subdirectories read into arrays and then those arrays be made available to Flux.  See for example <link>https://fluxml.ai/tutorials/2020/09/15/deep-learning-flux.html </link>. I also wonder if someone else may have already imported those images into a archived Flux package --  you might want to look for such an item on Github, if there is one.

Comment: @erroDecoder if you can, please add additional context to your question, as it stand, it is not clear what you are asking right now.

Comment: @logankilpatrick what I am simply asking is how to import images https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia in julia using the flux package. and the sample code that I posted its me just trying to do so but not working.